# Jackson XML Serialization - Remove Field Tags

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson

I need to generate this XML:

```
<CRequest>
  <abc:Name>Smith</abc:Name>
  <abc:FirstName>John</abc:Surname>
  <abc:Age>12</abc:Age>
  <abc:Name>Jones</abc:Name>
  <abc:FirstName>Jake</abc:Surname>
  <abc:Age>10</abc:Age>
  <abc:Name>Johnson</abc:Name>
  <abc:FirstName>Paul</abc:Surname>
  <abc:Age>12</abc:Age>
</CRequest>
```

However, the best I could do was:

```
<CRequest>
  <children>
    <abc:Name>Smith</abc:Name>
    <abc:FirstName>John</abc:Surname>
    <abc:Age>12</abc:Age>
  </children>
  <children>
    <abc:Name>Jones</abc:Name>
    <abc:FirstName>Jake</abc:Surname>
    <abc:Age>12</abc:Age>
  </children>
  <children>
    <abc:Name>Johnson</abc:Name>
    <abc:FirstName>Paul</abc:Surname>
    <abc:Age>12</abc:Age>
  </children>
</CRequest>
```

I have the following Java classes:

```
@JsonRootName("CRequest")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class ChildrenRequest {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Child> children= new ArrayList<>();
    ...
```

and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"Name", "FirstName", "Age"})
public class Child{

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "abc:Name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("Surname")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "FirstName")
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("Age")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "abc:Age")
    private String age;
    ...
```

Is there a way to get rid of the children tags?

PS: Without "useWrapping = false" I get two children tags for every child.

Comment: Not sure if there's an XML equivalent but JsonUnwrapped annotation has worked for me to do the same thing in JSON  - https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html

Comment: Though to be honest the useWrapping = false does sound like the same thing. Thinking about it, I've never used it on a list of objects, only when skipping a level in an object graph. I'm guessing the list may be the issue as the final XML looks a bit non-standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement custom serialiser for request class:

```
class ChildrenRequestJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ChildrenRequest> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(ChildrenRequest value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        ToXmlGenerator xmlGen = (ToXmlGenerator) gen;
        writeStartObject(xmlGen);
        JsonSerializer<Object> childSerializer = serializers.findValueSerializer(Child.class).unwrappingSerializer(NameTransformer.NOP);
        for (Child child : value.getChildren()) {
            childSerializer.serialize(child, gen, serializers);
        }
        xmlGen.writeEndObject();
    }

    private void writeStartObject(ToXmlGenerator xmlGen) throws IOException {
        final XmlMapper mapper = (XmlMapper) xmlGen.getCodec();
        final PropertyName rootName = mapper.getSerializationConfig().findRootName(ChildrenRequest.class);

        xmlGen.setNextName(new QName("", rootName.getSimpleName()));
        xmlGen.writeStartObject();
    }
}
```

And you can register serialiser as below:

```
@JsonRootName("CRequest")
@JsonSerialize(using = ChildrenRequestJsonSerializer.class)
class ChildrenRequest
```

See also:

- [@JsonSerialize - How to create a wrapper at runtime and use default serialization for the object fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411455/jsonserialize-how-to-create-a-wrapper-at-runtime-and-use-default-serializatio)
- [Dynamic root element with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930208/dynamic-root-element-with-jackson)
- [JacksonXmlRootElement with dynamic localName value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58382190/jacksonxmlrootelement-with-dynamic-localname-value)